# How to change the last row of a group unsing groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to set the last entry of an ID to isDeprecated=True if it's not in latest_dates. It is important to change only the last one in order to know when is was set to isDeprecated.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'ID': [23, 23, 24, 26, 26, 28, 28, 28, 17, 17, 17, 19, 20],
    'Date': ['01.01.2023', '06.01.2023', '09.01.2023', '02.01.2023', '09.01.2023',
             '01.01.2023', '02.01.2023', '03.01.2023', '28.12.2022', '29.12.2022',
             '09.01.2023', '09.01.2023', '28.12.2022']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')

df['isDeprecated'] = False

latest_dates = df['Date'].unique()

latest_dates.sort()


#array(['2023-01-06T00:00:00.000000000','2023-01-09T00:00:00.000000000'],dtype='datetime64[ns]')
latest_dates = latest_dates[-2:]

#logic here

print(df)
```

The expected output should look like:

| ID | Date | isDeprecated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 01.01.2023 | False |
| 23 | 06.01.2023 | False |
| 24 | 09.01.2023 | False |
| 26 | 02.01.2023 | False |
| 26 | 09.01.2023 | False |
| 28 | 01.01.2023 | False |
| 28 | 02.01.2023 | False |
| 28 | 03.01.2023 | True |
| 17 | 28.12.2022 | False |
| 17 | 29.12.2022 | False |
| 17 | 09.01.2023 | False |
| 19 | 09.01.2023 | False |
| 20 | 28.12.2022 | True |

Comment: What do you mean by "the last row"? In terms of position? date? What is the logic to compute `latest_dates`?

Comment: Latest_dates contains the last/latest two dates of the whole column date. I would like to mark the last/jungest entry of an ID, but only the last one, if it’s not in one of these dates. This logic should mark scraped articles if they’re not found within the last two crawls, but only the last/jungest entry to see when it was outdated.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't seem to match this logic. Also, please provide a reproducible input, not images

Comment: Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test if not match last value by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and last value by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
m = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].transform('last').isin(latest_dates)

df['isDeprecated'] = ~m & ~df['ID'].duplicated(keep='last')
print (df)
    ID       Date  isDeprecated
0   23 2023-01-01         False
1   23 2023-01-06         False
2   24 2023-01-09         False
3   26 2023-01-02         False
4   26 2023-01-09         False
5   28 2023-01-01         False
6   28 2023-01-02         False
7   28 2023-01-03          True
8   17 2022-12-28         False
9   17 2022-12-29         False
10  17 2023-01-09         False
11  19 2023-01-09         False
12  20 2022-12-28          True
```